# Como somar valores de uma array de objetos[JS], somente com funções e loop for?

Tags: javascript, array, funções, loop, objetos

Eis a questão:

**Soma de despesas e receitas**

Crie um programa que calcula a soma de receitas e despesas de usuários e no fim retorna o saldo (receitas - despesas).

Utilize o array de usuários abaixo:

```js
const usuarios = [
      {
        nome: "Salvio",
        receitas: [115.3, 48.7, 98.3, 14.5],
        despesas: [85.3, 13.5, 19.9]
      },
      {
        nome: "Marcio",
        receitas: [24.6, 214.3, 45.3],
        despesas: [185.3, 12.1, 120.0]
      },
      {
        nome: "Lucia",
        receitas: [9.8, 120.3, 340.2, 45.3],
        despesas: [450.2, 29.9]
      }
    ];
```

Percorra o array de usuários e para cada usuário chame uma função chamada `calculaSaldo` que recebe como parâmetro as receitas e despesas do usuário:

```
function calculaSaldo(receitas, despesas) {}
```

Crie uma segunda função que recebe como parâmetro um array de números e retorna a soma deles e use-a para calcular a soma de receitas e despesas dentro da função `calculaSaldo`:

```
function somaNumeros(numeros) {
  // Soma todos números dentro do array "numeros"
}
```

A função `calculaSaldo` deve utilizar a função `somaNumeros` para calcular a soma de receitas e despesas e no fim retornar o saldo do usuário, ou seja `receitas - despesas`.

Pesquisando, vi que a melhor forma de fazer isso, é com o reduce. Porém, o desafio consiste em fazer utilizando `Funções` e `Loops`.

Já tem dois dias que tento resolver, mas não consegui. 
Consegui, apenas, fazer uma função que calcula o total do valor da array.

```js
const usuarios = [
  {
    nome: "Salvio",
    receitas: [115.3, 48.7, 98.3, 14.5],
    despesas: [85.3, 13.5, 19.9]
  },
  {
    nome: "Marcio",
    receitas: [24.6, 214.3, 45.3],
    despesas: [185.3, 12.1, 120.0]
  },
  {
    nome: "Lucia",
    receitas: [9.8, 120.3, 340.2, 45.3],
    despesas: [450.2, 29.9]
  }
];

function somaNumeros(numeros) {
  let soma = 0;
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numeros.length ; i++) {
    soma += numeros[i]
  } return soma
}
console.log(somaNumeros(usuarios[0].receitas))
```

Mas não consegui passar para os outros passos.

Agradeceria se alguém me desse uma luz.

Comment: `somaNumeros(usuarios[0].receitas) - somaNumeros(usuarios[0].despesas)`? Aí coloca isso dentro de um loop com o acesso via índice "dinâmico" para fazer para cada usuário.

Answer (score 1):

*"um programa que calcula a soma de receitas e despesas de usuários"* - a minha interpretação é que o pretendido é uma array com a soma de cada utilizador. A ser assim precisas de um `.map` pois queres uma array com o mesmo numero de entradas, na mesma ordem (a soma para o seu utilizador respetivo).

Em relação a `calculaSaldo` e `somaNumeros`... começando por `somaNumeros` aqui sim é um `.reduce` clássico, bem simples... Em relação a `calculaSaldo` a ideia é converter os numeros em valores que possam ser passados a `somaNumeros` com o sinal (positivo/negativo) certo.

Uma sugestão seria assim:

```js
const usuarios = [{
    nome: "Salvio",
    receitas: [115.3, 48.7, 98.3, 14.5],
    despesas: [85.3, 13.5, 19.9]
  },
  {
    nome: "Marcio",
    receitas: [24.6, 214.3, 45.3],
    despesas: [185.3, 12.1, 120.0]
  },
  {
    nome: "Lucia",
    receitas: [9.8, 120.3, 340.2, 45.3],
    despesas: [450.2, 29.9]
  }
];

function calculaSaldo(utilizador) {
  const entradas = utilizador.receitas;
  // e agora juntamos as despesas com o sinal certo:
  utilizador.despesas.forEach(nr => entradas.push(nr * -1));

  return somaNumeros(entradas);
}

function somaNumeros(numeros) {
  return numeros.reduce((sum, nr) => sum + nr, 0);
}

const somas = usuarios.map(calculaSaldo);
console.log(somas);
console.log(somas.map((soma, i) => `${usuarios[i].nome}: ${soma}`).join('\n'));
```